# Statistical Test on Categorical Data with Repetitions?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have a list of 5 categories such as A, B, C, D, and E
and I need to compare two cohorts X and Y who fall into either of the above 5 categories, meaning X can get categorized into A and B or several of them.

Now I know that, had these been independent I would have used a Chi-Square test. But since these are not, what would be an appropriate test to use?

Sample Data:
[image]

Comment: What do your data look like?

Comment: @NickCox Edited and attached sample data. Basically, I am dealing with user ratings. I have obtained the following categories from the user comments.

Now the issue is a comment can be something like:
'I faced echo and had to disconnect'

This gets classified in both Echo and Disconnect which is the case where the independence does not exist anymore.

Comment: There's nothing non-standard about your example.

Comment: @NickCox Posted an incomplete comment by mistake. Kindly see the above comment and let me know if the problem statement is clear. Thanks for the response

Comment: What other possible relations exist? That is are there other cases where a user could classify it in more than 1 class?

Comment: Yes. Not every time it gets classified into more than 1 class but sometimes. Hence the assumption that categories are independent fails and I cannot use a Chi-Square for testing a statistical significance.

Comment: If for example you would add 1 to the Choppy count and 1 to the Echo count if someone said (Choppy, Echo) then such double counting violates chi-square. The best I can suggest is to split counts and assign 1/2 to each. Similar comments for triple and quadruple mentions.

Comment: @NickCox that seems like a unique suggestion. will try it out. thanks again